# graphql in react, argument always null

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql

I'm trying to get an ID of an HTML element (id="1") and pass it to a graphql mutation. The issue is that no matter what I do, the argument is always nulled and I get a graphql error stating expecting ID! but found null.

Here's the mutation:

```
const T_TOGGLE = gql`
    mutation tToggle($idx: ID!) {
        tToggle(t_id: $idx)
    }`;
```

The declaration:

```
 const [tToggle] = useMutation(T_TOGGLE, {variables: {t_id: idx}});
```

and when the onChange event happens, it executes this code:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const idx = event.target.id;

     tToggle({variables: {t_id: idx}});
};
```

I've tried a bunch of things, and I can't seem to figure this out. Any ideas?

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "idx": Expected non-null, found null.
```

Comment: Your mutation defines a variable called `idx`, but your code uses either `t_dd` or `t_id` as variable names. The error names  yet another variable, called `id`.

Comment: @robertklep sorry, the error is "idx", I'm not sure why that got changed. The t_id is the field name in the database, is that the wrong way to assign it? Every tutorial I've found sets it up that way.

Comment: If the variable is called `idx`, you need to use that in `variables` (`{ idx : idx }`). I'm not familiar enough with React so not sure if your usage of `useMutation` is correct (with `@vue/apollo-composable` it would be different).

Answer (score 0):

```
const T_TOGGLE = gql`
    mutation tToggle($idx: ID!) {
        tToggle(t_id: $idx)
    }`;
```

In your mutation `tToggle` you are defining a variable `$idx` which is then provided to the field `tToggle` as `t_id` parameter.

What you probably want is:

```
 const [tToggle] = useMutation(T_TOGGLE, {variables: { idx: idx}});
```

And/Or

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const idx = event.target.id;
    tToggle({variables: { idx: idx }});
};
```

`idx` instead of `t_id`, `idx` is the name of your mutation variable while `t_id` is the name of a field parameter

Note that you are not required to provided variables to your call `tToggle({ variables: { idx: idx } })` if they are already provided when calling useMutation and you do not need to override them